# Constructive proof of strong normalization for simply typed lambda calculus

Tags: agda, lambda-calculus, normalization

I'm reading Girard's [*Proofs and Types*](https://www.pls-lab.org/en/Proofs_and_Types), and in section 4.4 he writes:

> Lemma: `t` is strongly normalisable iff there is a number `ν(t)` which bounds the
> length of every normalisation sequence beginning with `t`.

He later uses this lemma in his proof that the STLC is strongly normalizing in section 6.2.3:

> (CR 3) Let `t` be neutral and suppose all the `t'` one step from `t` are
> reducible. Let `u`
> be a reducible term of type `U`; we want to show that `t u` is reducible. By
> induction hypothesis (CR 1) for `U`, we know that `u` is strongly normalisable;
> so we can reason by induction on `ν(u)`.

The lemma uses a version of [Konig's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_lemma) which IIUC is not provable constructively.  Is there a constructive proof of strong normalization for the simply typed lambda calculus?  Specifically something I can (try to) translate into Agda?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Dan Doel says in the comments, the reason Kőnig's lemma is used is that Girard's definition of strong normalization is constructively too weak. It's defined as the non-existence of infinite reduction sequences.

We can use the following definition instead: a term is strongly normalizing if every one-step reduct of it is strongly normalizing (inductively). In Agda:

```
data SN {Γ A} (t : Tm Γ A) : Set where
  sn : (∀ {t'} → t ~> t' → SN t') → SN t
```

Note that if a term is normal then it has no one-step reduct so `SN t` holds vacuously.

This is also called accessibility of `t` with respect to `~>`. I believe it originates from Aczel's [An Introduction to Inductive Definitions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0049237X08711200). This is a common `SN` definition in formalizations. The oldest formalized example that I know is in [Altenkirch's thesis](https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Epsztxa/publ/phd93.pdf).

The advantage of `SN t` is that we can do induction on it. Operationally, we can make a "recursive call" on any one-step reduct of a strongly normalizing term. You could also look at my [Agda formalization](https://github.com/AndrasKovacs/misc-stuff/blob/master/agda/STLCStrongNorm/StrongNorm.agda) of Girard's Chapter 6, which uses this `SN`.

Comment: I updated my question to be more specific about where Girard uses the lemma in the strong normalization proof.  I'll have to look carefully at your code to see how you got around it.

Comment: The difference (I think) is that Girard's use of Kőnig's lemma is only necessary because "strongly normalizable" is defined weakly. It is one of the classically equivalent ways to say, "reduction is well-founded." The Agda defines this in the constructively appropriate way, where a proof that a value is "accessible" justifies induction over its predecessors. Kőnig's lemma is used to recover a _natural number_ to justify the same induction, but this is unnecessary if you set things up appropriately.

Comment: You're both right. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 7):

For a modern take on the proof, you can have a look at [POPLmark Reloaded](https://poplmark-reloaded.github.io/).

The paper's appendix explains in great details what the (sometimes technical) proofs are. The paper comes with various formalisations in Agda, Beluga, Coq, F*, and Lean 3. The Agda formalisation uses sized types which are now marked as unsafe so a new version of the formalisation seen to be safe by a recent version of Agda would be a welcomed addition!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135106/discussion-on-answer-by-gallais-constructive-proof-of-strong-normalization-for-s).